# Single Array Value to show multiple tableview on one viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am developing Iphone Application.Using Three table view on Single viewcontroller. value show on those tableview's on single array but problem is that those array value show on first tableview not on other two tableview's. please help Thanks in advance

code..

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [_arrayResult count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    MEObject *obj = [_arrayResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (tableView == _tableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text= obj.emp_client_name;
    }
    if (tableView == _secondTableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text= obj.emp_event_name;
    }
    if (tableView == _thirdTableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text=obj.emp_client_name;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Did you set the `dataSource` and `delegate` for all 3 table views?

Comment: Why not just have a single table with 3 sections?

Comment: can you show me the code for _arrayResult data add & reload table logic?

Comment: yes set dataSource and delegates for all 3 table's

Comment: NSArray *array = [[response objectForKey:@"data"]objectForKey:@"response"];
        for (NSDictionary *dic in array) {
            MEObject *obj = [[MEObject alloc]init];
            obj.emp_client_id = [dic valueForKey:@"client_id"];
            obj.emp_client_name = [dic valueForKey:@"client_name"];
            obj.emp_event_id = [dic valueForKey:@"event_id"];
            obj.emp_event_name = [dic valueForKey:@"event_name"];
            [_arrayResult addObject:obj];
        }
        [_tableView reloadData];
    }

Comment: You can always edit your question to show additional code/clarifications. It helps in understanding the context. As I understand from your comment, If that is only the piece of code that reloads the table; you are always reloading `_tableView` which is why you are facing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please cross check if you are setting datasource and delegates of all 3 tables to viewcontroller.

When you set your _arrayResult, you need to reload all 3 table view

```
_arrayResult = @[a,b,c];
[table1 reloadData];
[table2 reloadData];
[table3 reloadData];
```

Answer (score -1):

After once you set the datasource/Delegate to the all three tableview. I haven't seen any datasource allocation as per your tableview. Like 
if tableview == tableview1 {

Return first array

}

Can you please try giving name to those tableview on outlet and then for each datasource and delegates function call as per your requirement but before check which tableview is displayed.